# String.format and arrays

Tags: java, printf

Is there a way to conveniently use `String.format` (or printf) to print the values in an array. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("Today is %tc and your args are %TAG", new Date(), args);
}
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
Today is Sat Oct 14 14:54:51 CEST 2017 and your args are uno dos tres
```

As the example suggests, I don't know how long the `args` array is? So far the only solution I've come up with is to first use `.format` to do get the first part of the string, then loop through the args array and append space separated chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `Arrays.toString(...)`, which will format it as ["unos", "dos", tres"], but I assume that is not what you want.

Usually I use the streaming api to collect the result into a string:
  `Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.printf("Today is %tc and your args are %s%n", new Date(), 
    Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
}
```

Comment: To clarify the edit undo: The %n in prinf means "use the platform specific code for going to a new line".

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a primitive array, you can wrap `args` in a list:

```
System.out.printf("%Tc %s", new Date(), Arrays.asList(args));
```

This then uses the implementation of `toString` for `List`.